# Sylius installation with error

Tags: symfony, yaml, sylius

I try to install Sylius but i have an error after projet installed

```
"/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bund    
    le/AdminBundle/Resources/config/grids/product_from_taxon.yml"
```

[image]

Comment: i suggest u to publish an issue on their official repos : https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=yaml%20issue cause its on their side, not your, since the issue is located in your vendor folder.

Comment: Did you modify that YAML file?

Comment: No i didn't i just type entry on installation process. After this Terminal prompte the Error. I dont change any thing i didn't yet open the project on IDE if you note the error is in the vendor ...

Answer (score 1):

This must be something in the environment of installation. Since 99% of people who install Sylius lately do not encounter this YAML parsing problem.

This issue was already posted, we are investigating it :)

Comment: Thank you so what i can do i Just like the Sylius and i want to test it :D

Answer (score 0):

What commands you used? Also, do you have all the required tools installed? Composer, npm and so on?

I installed one yesterday and it worked just fine.

Comment: Every things is installed as i literally followed the documentation and I do what should i Do !